# Exibir <span> ao dar hover em um <a> com transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Gostaria de verificar se há possibilidade de exibir uma span ao passar o mouse sobre uma tag `<a>` com `transition`. O HTML está da seguinte forma:

```
<a id="id-a" style="padding:0px" class="btn btn-link" onclick="realizarAcao()" role="button" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fas fa-projector me-md-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Meu Texto</span></a>
```

Até o momento fiz em CSS:

```
#id-a span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}

#id-a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}

#id-a span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Acontece que o texto "Meu Texto" está sendo exibido com a `transition`, porém, ele só será exibido ao dar o hover no próprio span do "Meu Texto". Gostaria que ele fosse exibido ao dar o hover no ícone que está dentro de `<a>`.

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu entendi vc quer que ao acionar um hover de algum elemento exibir outro componente (o span no caso)
Você pode fazer o seguinte primeiramente oculte seu span assim:

```
span {
display: none;
}
```

e utiliza um hover que afeta outro elemento dessa forma:

```
a:hover + span{
display: block; // coloque um valor para que o span apareça novamente
transition: 500ms;
backgroud-color: red;
```

}

e assim o seu input começa invisível e quando a pagina carrega e quando for acionado o hover no elemento A o span irá aparecer com as propriedades que vc inseriu, mas eu indico utiliza elementos DOM para esse tipo de solução, qualquer duvida estou a disposição.
dica: Utilize classes nos seus elementos para acessar no arquivo css.

Comment: Obrigada Matheus!

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que entendi, você quer dar o hover no icon e fazer o texto do span aparecer. Para isso, basta você fazer uma pequena modificação no seu CSS:

```css
#id-a span {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}

#id-a {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}

#id-a i:hover ~ span /* aqui é a linha que mudou */  {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

O seletor ~ seleciona o próximo irmão.
[Referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).